# inefficient usage of array_intersect

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df = df.withColumn('valid_tokens', array_intersect(
                array([lit(x) for x in
                       broadcasted_valid_list.value]),
                col("input_tokens")))
```

I have an array type column input_tokens. (df ~10k rows)
I have a broadcasted list which has over 100k values.

I only need those tokens in that row which belong to this list.

array_intersect is taking too long as for each row it's doing that 1million search per token (~10 tokens per ArrayType row value)

Is there a different operation that can help here? valid tokens as a dictionary but then what would replace array_intersect if at all that'll help?

Answer (score 0):

The code `[lit(x) for x in broadcasted_valid_list.value]` is actually run on the driver and creates an array with ~100k values and then tries to send it as an execution plan to the drivers.
This is too long of a plan and causes the lag you are talking about.

**NEW - VERSION 2**

we still save the list of valid tokens but we first expldoe all tokens of the input, join on the tokens and group back on the input id to get to the needed format.

```
# mock - save to disk valid tokens
arr = list(range(19, 105000))
pddf = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["id"])
pddf.to_parquet("valid_tokens.parquet")

# read as spark dataframe and collect all tokens to one array row
df = spark.read.parquet("valid_tokens.parquet")

my_input.alias('input') \
.select('id', explode('input_tokens').alias('input_token')) \
.join(df.alias('good_tokens'), on=col('input_token') == col('good_tokens.id')) \
.groupBy('input.id') \
.agg(collect_list('input_token').alias('input_tokens')) \
.show()
```

**VERSION 1**

The easiest way I found of running a similar code of yours is saving somewhere the list of 100k valid token.

```
# mock - save to disk valid tokens
arr = list(range(19, 105000))
pddf = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["id"])
pddf.to_parquet("valid_tokens.parquet")

# read as spark dataframe and collect all tokens to one array row
df = spark.read.parquet("valid_tokens.parquet")
df_agg = df.agg(collect_list('id').alias('ids')) #one row for all tokens

# input of 100 rows with 3 tokens: 10, 20, 50
my_input = spark.range(100) \
.withColumn("input_tokens", array(lit(10), lit(20), lit(50))) \
.drop('id')

my_input \
.crossJoin(df_agg) \
.withColumn('final', array_intersect('input_tokens', 'ids').alias('final')) \
.select('input_tokens', 'final') \
.show(truncate=0)
```

As can be seen 10 was dropped as it's not in the range we saved as parquet file.
[image]

Comment: Somehow this increased the time by 20%.. can a hashmap be used instead of list? but that'd probably need to be within a udf as a global variable @walking

Comment: I don't think UDF are needed, I found another solution which might be OK. edited the comment.